# Unable to start OpenSearch on Mac with podman [1]: memory locking requested for opensearch process but memory is not locked

Tags: opensearch, podman

I was trying to start an OpenSearch cluster following the [official doc](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/quickstart/)

But I was presented with the error

```
opensearch-node1       | ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
opensearch-node1       | [1]: memory locking requested for opensearch process but memory is not locked
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in the [compose file](https://github.com/opensearch-project/documentation-website/blob/2.11/assets/examples/docker-compose.yml#L11), it says

`bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping`

There are 2 ways to address the issue

1. Change the above line to false
2. SSH into the podman machine and add the following lines to `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* soft memlock -1
* hard memlock -1
```